# Numbers looping more than I want

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, random

Here I am creating a program where I can add marbles to a bag. I am also assigning a random name to the number of marbles that I enter, hence why I have an array of names. The size of my name array is 10 and holds ten name values. When I go to add marbles to the bag, my code loops through and say I add 5 marbles to the bag, instead of going: 0-----Andrew, 1-----Dustin, and so on up to 5. it actually loops I think 6 different times.

I have tried playing around with my for loops and arrays.

```
void addmarbles(){

int x;
        cout<< "how many random marbles would you like to enter?" << endl;
          cin >>choice;



srand(time(0));




          for(int i=0; i<arraysize; i++) {

for(x = 0; x<=choice; x++){
int index = rand() % arraysize;

            string swap = names[i];
            names[i] = names[index];
            names[index] = swap;
cout<< x<< "------------" << names[index] <<endl;
}
}



              bag += choice;
                cout << "The current amount of marbles in the bag is: "<< bag <<endl;

                main();

}
```

expected the output say if I add 5 marbles to be:

0------------andrew
1------------vicki
2------------josh
3------------branden
4------------ryan
5------------dustin

but instead its this:

0------------andrew
1------------andrew
2------------vicki
3------------josh
4------------josh
5------------ryan
0------------vicki
1------------vicki
2------------ryan
3------------josh
4------------dustin
5------------mark
0------------branden
1------------justin
2------------smitty
3------------branden
4------------justin
5------------carter
0------------ryan
1------------josh
2------------justin
3------------andrew
4------------mark
5------------justin
0------------vicki
1------------justin
2------------carter
3------------andrew
4------------vicki
5------------andrew
0------------vicki
1------------branden
2------------vicki
3------------vicki
4------------andrew
5------------dustin
0------------justin
1------------justin
2------------mark
3------------mark
4------------andrew
5------------ryan
0------------branden
1------------branden
2------------mark
3------------ryan
4------------mark
5------------branden
0------------carter
1------------justin
2------------dustin
3------------justin
4------------mark
5------------dustin
0------------justin
1------------josh
2------------vicki
3------------carter
4------------justin
5------------andrew

Comment: remove this loop : `for(int i=0; i<arraysize; i++) {`

Comment: Have one loop that adds the marbles to the array, and then a second loop **afterwards** that randomizes the array. Your code isn't working because you've combined these two loops.

Comment: Please fix the code indentation, it's all over the place.

Comment: x<=choice would mess you up by 1, since x is 0 based. I'm not sure why you get the tea of them, other than maybe do you not need nested loops? Why do you need both loops?

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you call main() at the end? It isn't usual to recurse into the main entry point, which is usually only called once.

Comment: @Ian4264 It's actually illegal to call `main`.